# Does anyone know how apps are published on the same day as new iOS release?

Tags: ios-appstore, xcode, app-store-connect, ios

Does anyone know how apps are published on the same day as new iOS release?

Because Xcode doesn't launch until then (except for the beta version). And you cannot publish apps using the beta version.

And getting the app reviewed takes at least 7 days.

Answer (score 2):

When the iOS Golden Master (GM) release is sent to developers, Apple also opens up app submissions for the new OS. They also appear to segment out releases targeted for the new OS so that apps are available, though there is no solid evidence for this.

For example, iOS 8 was released on Sept 17th, 2014. [On September 9, 2014, Apple opened submissions for apps targeting iOS 8](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09082014b):

> Prepare your apps for the App Store by downloading the iOS 8 and Xcode
>   6 GM seeds now. With these latest seeds, Swift is now final and you
>   can submit your iOS apps written with Swift to the App Store. Learn
>   about iOS 8 for Developers.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the Golden Master release? I have my iOS 9 app ready.

Comment: It has not yet been released.  Apple will send emails to registered developers when the GM is released, and it will be covered by all the Apple news sites.